# Linq with union on 3 tables

Tags: linq, union

I like to use linq to do a union on 3 tables.
Not sure why something like the following would not work:

```
var repdata = (from p in db.Table1
               select p)
                       .Union(from p in Table2
                        select p);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Union` only works with the same element type. You could use:

```
var data = db.Table1.Select(p => new { p.Value1, p.Value2 })
     .Union(db.Table2.Select(q => new { q.Value1, q.Value2 })
     .Union(db.Table3.Select(r => new { Value1 = r.Alias1, Value2 = r.Other });
```

Here the anonymous type serves as a common type to project all three tables onto, so that `Union` can work.

Comment: Jon, I am getting an error when it this way. Meaning, the program will not even run. What do Value1, Value2, etc represent?

Comment: @NatePet: Whatever properties you're trying to access from the tables. You haven't told us anything about the tables, so I made up some names, and showed how to use projections if the names aren't the same in all three tables.

Comment: I tried to match up the tables in my table but not workig as expected: `var data = db.TerritoryReps.Select(p => new { p.Rpfn, p.Rpln }) .Union(db.RegionalManagers.Select(q => new { q.Rfn, q.Rln }) .Union(db.DistrictManagers.Select(r => new { r.Dfn, r.Dln });`

Comment: @Nate Pet: Jon has already shown you how to solve this problem. Please read his answer and his comment again!

Comment: @NatePet: Those anonymous types don't have the same property names, do they? You need to be using the same anonymous type for all three tables, which means using the same property names and types in the same order.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Jon, I need to add another column to each table that identifies what table the fields came from. How you do create a new column inside of the above statment and give it a value?

Comment: @NatePet: How about `new { ..., TableId = 1 }` (with other numbers for the different tables)?