# How to get the correct data with a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

The question evolved from the original post, so to broaden the results I have added a seperate question.

the original quest was answered, but in doing so I ran into a new problem that has stumped me.
See original post here: [LINQ beginner, table joining query for document version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931830/linq-beginner-table-joining-query-for-document-version)

This is for a document revision system.  And we are using two tables.  As soon as a user created a new document the information is added to the `Document` table.  At this time the document table has a revision which is set to 0 and a dateApproved which is set to null.  The primary key is documentID.

Now if the user edits that document a line is created in a new table `Version`.

Here is the Linq I have that is correctly returning all the documents that need to be approved (2 brand new documents which only have a line in the `Documents` table, and 1 document that had been edited so it has a line in Documents and `Version`).

```
var docs = db.IPACS_Document
               .Where(x => x.dateApproved == null 
                          || x.IPACS_Version.Any(y => y.dateApproved == null));
```

The above Linq correctly identifies all 3 documents that need approval, however for the document that has a line in the `Documents` table and the `Version` table.  It is returning the information from the Document table (when in reality I need the information from the Version table for items that have been edited).

Is there a way to return the Version table information for documents that have been edited, it already correctly returns the information for brand new documents.

Answer (score 1):

You need `IEnumerable.Union` but it works only with same element types. You have 2 types: `Version` and `Document`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854366/1594178) answer how to use it.